# Grouping values in comma delimited string

Tags: python, string

I have the following string:

```
"paid,paid,paid,paid,unpaid,paid,paid,paid,paid,unpaid,unpaid,unpaid,paid,paid,Pinterest,unpaid,Pinterest,unpaid,unpaid"
```

I want to turn it into this:

```
"paid x4, unpaid x1, paid x4, unpaid x3, paid x2, Pinterest x1, unpaid x1, Pinterest x1, unpaid x2"
```

Basically, I want to group the items together if the next item is the same as the previous one and get a count of the number of times this holds true. So in the example, four unpaid in a row turn into `paid x4` then one unpaid in a row turns into `unpaid x1` then four paid in a row turns into `unpaid x4`, and so on.

I wrote the following function that I think accomplishes what I want. Is there a more pythonic/efficient way to do this?

```
counter = 1
split_string = string_test.split(',')
len_string = len(split_string)
new_string = ''
for num, string in enumerate(split_string):  
    # Edge case: last string in list
    if len_string == num + 1:
        if split_string[num] == split_string[num-1]:
            new_string += split_string[num] + ' x' + str(counter)
            #print("new string:", new_string)
        else:
            new_string += split_string[num] + ' x1 '
        break

    else:
        if split_string[num] == split_string[num+1]:
            counter += 1 
            #print("string match")
        else:
            new_string += split_string[num] + ' x' + str(counter) + ', '
            #print("new string:", new_string)
            counter = 1
print(new_string)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in one (not too complicated) line using `itertools.groupby`.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> ', '.join(['{} x{}'.format(w, len(list(ws))) for w, ws in groupby(string_test.split(','))])
'paid x4, unpaid x1, paid x4, unpaid x3, paid x2, Pinterest x1, unpaid x1, Pinterest x1, unpaid x2'
```

It's arguably a little cleaner using f-strings introduced in Python 3.6, if you can use that:

```
>>> ', '.join([f'{w} x{len(list(ws))}' for w, ws in groupby(string_test.split(','))])
```